# Dataframe lookup with lists, and multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, arraylist

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID1': ['2456-AA', '2457-AA', '2458-AA', '2657-AA'],
                    'QT': [10, 5, 45, 10],
                    'ID2': [['5365-BB'], ['5365-BB', '6552-BB'], ['6552-BB', '7878-BB'], ['5365-BB', '2323-BB', '2556-BB']]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID2': ['5365-BB', '6552-BB', '5858-BB', '2323-BB'],
                    'TASK': ['Check pot', 'Check Equip1.', 'Check Equip2.', 'Check Equip3.']})

df1
       ID1  QT                          ID2
0  2456-AA  10                    [5365-BB]
1  2457-AA   5           [5365-BB, 6552-BB]
2  2458-AA  45           [6552-BB, 7878-BB]
3  2657-AA  10  [5365-BB, 2323-BB, 2556-BB]

df2
       ID2           TASK
0  5365-BB      Check pot
1  6552-BB  Check Equip1.
2  5858-BB  Check Equip2.
3  2323-BB  Check Equip3.
```

I would like to look up the values in ID2, df2 in ID2, df1 and return the ID1 values as a list to each ID2 in df2. The end result would look something like this:

```
df2
       ID2           TASK                          ID1
0  5365-BB      Check pot  [2456-AA, 2457-AA, 2657-AA]
1  6552-BB  Check Equip1.           [2457-AA, 2458-AA]
2  5858-BB  Check Equip2.                           []
3  2323-BB  Check Equip3.                    [2657-AA]
```

I've tried to complete this re-using a method I did before with lambda but I keep returning blank values.
Thank you for any support,

**EDIT**

It is worth mentioning that the datasets i'm trying to work on have more columns than inside this example.  Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: The values in `ID2` column in `df1` contains list of strings, right?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma yep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's `explode` and `groupby` the dataframe `df1` on column `ID2` and `agg` `ID1` using `list` to create a mapping series `m`. Then `map` the `ID2` in `df2` with  the series `m`, finally use boolean indexing to fill the `nan` values with `[]`:

```
m = df1.explode('ID2').groupby('ID2')['ID1'].agg(list)
df2['ID1'] = df2['ID2'].map(m)
df2.loc[df2['ID1'].isna(), 'ID1'] = [[]] * df2['ID1'].isna().sum()
```

---

```
print(df2)

       ID2           TASK                          ID1
0  5365-BB      Check pot  [2456-AA, 2457-AA, 2657-AA]
1  6552-BB  Check Equip1.           [2457-AA, 2458-AA]
2  5858-BB  Check Equip2.                           []
3  2323-BB  Check Equip3.                    [2657-AA]
```

Comment: Thank you for your work. For `df2.loc[df2['ID1'].isna(), 'ID1'] = [[]] * df2['ID1'].isna().sum()` What do I need to do in order to turn this into a dataframe?

Comment: @Ventoii it's just an statement which is used here to fill the `nan` values in `df2` in the `ID1` column..The resulting dataframe is `df2`.

Comment: @Ventoii Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

A lambda function is no good idea here. What you should be doing is recreating dataframes without lists and afterward merge datasets (and at the end, recreate lists if you really need it) ; something like this (I haven't tested it) :

```
array = df1.values.tolist()
array = [[id1, qt, id2] for [id1_list, qt, id2_list] in array for id1 in id1_list for id2 in id2_list]
df1_altered = pd.DataFrame(array, columns=['ID1', 'QT', 'ID2'])

array = df2.values.tolist()
array = [[task, id2] for [id2_list, task] in array for id2 in id2_list]
df2_altered = pd.DataFrame(array, columns=['Task', 'ID2'])

df = df2_altered.merge(df1_altered, on='ID2', how='left')
df = df.groupby(['ID2', 'Task'])['ID1'].apply(lambda x:[y for y in list(x) if not pd.isnull(y)]).reset_index(drop=False)
df['ID2'] = df['ID2'].apply(lambda x:[x])
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I was trying out the approach you've put. Unfortunately I get the error: "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)". Do you have the same error?

Comment: @Ventoii - I fixed two mistakes on this code - but I didn't raised the same exception as you on my side... Check if this is now working for you (BTW for future questions : please paste the code to create your dataframe inside the question, it will save some time for people trying to help ! ;-) )

Comment: @Ventoii - anything new here ?

Comment: Hi @tgrandje, I'm not ignoring. Still troubleshooting. The issue is the dataset i'm using has more columns of data. So I think when i use the `array = df1.values.tolist()` it unpacks a huge amount of values, and finds it difficult to then analyse all of the data?

Comment: Uh, that maybe an error while doing comprehension's list then...  Did you checked how many variables you are using while iterating over the array ?

Comment: And if you want to limit the unpacking of the array to those 3 columns, you may replace array = df1.values.tolist() by array = df1[['ID1', 'QT', 'ID2']].values.tolist()

Comment: I have made the adjustments. How ever my compuiter crashes. The C: drives freezes, and i'm forced to restart.

Comment: can you insert "print("1st step");time.sleep(3)" between operations to show what is going on ?

Comment: Thank you for all of your tips. They helped me to identify the issue. `array = [[id1, qt, id2] for [id1_list, qt, id2_list] in array for id1 in id1_list for id2 in id2_list]` is creating an array for each individual character. I think this is why it fails when trying to emerge...Do you have this issue?

Comment: No, not using a small dataframe as the one you posted. This line is a double comprehension list. What does print(array = [[id1, qt, id2] for [id1_list, qt, id2_list] in array[:10] for id1 in id1_list for id2 in id2_list]) gives ?

Comment: (just to make sure : you don't have empty id2s or id1s' lists in your dataframe ?)

Comment: [['2', 10, '5365-BB'],
 ['4', 10, '5365-BB'],
 ['5', 10, '5365-BB'],
 ['6', 10, '5365-BB'],
 ['-', 10, '5365-BB'],
 ['A', 10, '5365-BB'],
 ['A', 10, '5365-BB'],
 ['2', 5, '5365-BB'],
 ['2', 5, '6552-BB'],
 ['4', 5, '5365-BB'],
 ['4', 5, '6552-BB'],
 ['5', 5, '5365-BB'],
 ['5', 5, '6552-BB'],
 ['7', 5, '5365-BB'],
 ['7', 5, '6552-BB'],
 ['-', 5, '5365-BB'],
 ['-', 5, '6552-BB'],
 ['A', 5, '5365-BB'],
 ['A', 5, '6552-BB'],
 ['A', 5, '5365-BB'],
 ['A', 5, '6552-BB'],
 ['2', 45, '6552-BB, 7878-BB'],
.........
It gives an array length of 49 lines

Comment: It is behaving as if id1 wasn't a column of lists

Comment: try this : array = [[id1_list, qt, id2] for [id1_list, qt, id2_list] in array for id2 in id2_list]

Comment: [['2456-AA', 10, '5365-BB'],
 ['2457-AA', 5, '5365-BB'],
 ['2457-AA', 5, '6552-BB'],
 ['2458-AA', 45, '6552-BB, 7878-BB'],
 ['2657-AA', 10, '5365-BB'],
 ['2657-AA', 10, '2323-BB'],
 ['2657-AA', 10, '2556-BB']]

It's much  better however, there is still a value that needs its own line '7878-BB'

Comment: Yes, that seems better. So if you run this, does it work ? array = [[id1_list, qt, id2] for [id1_list, qt, id2_list] in array for id2 in id2_list];df1_altered = pd.DataFrame(array, columns=['ID1', 'QT', 'ID2']) ;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223639/discussion-between-tgrandje-and-ventoii).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with aggregate `list`, then add not exist values from `df2['ID2']` by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) and pass to [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) or [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
s = (df1.explode('ID2')
        .groupby('ID2')['ID1']
        .agg(list)
        .reindex(df2['ID2'].unique(), fill_value=[]))
df2['ID1'] = df2['ID2'].map(s)
print (df2)
       ID2           TASK                          ID1
0  5365-BB      Check pot  [2456-AA, 2457-AA, 2657-AA]
1  6552-BB  Check Equip1.           [2457-AA, 2458-AA]
2  5858-BB  Check Equip2.                           []
3  2323-BB  Check Equip3.                    [2657-AA]
```

---

```
df2 = df2.join(s.rename('ID1'), on='ID2')
print (df2)

       ID2           TASK                          ID1
0  5365-BB      Check pot  [2456-AA, 2457-AA, 2657-AA]
1  6552-BB  Check Equip1.           [2457-AA, 2458-AA]
2  5858-BB  Check Equip2.                           []
3  2323-BB  Check Equip3.                    [2657-AA]
```

Answer (score 0):

you'd need to have a "common ID" in both data sets.
The ID2 in df2 is fine, but the ID2 in df1 would need some manipulation.
You may need to separate the ID2 in df1 into 3 columns,
For example:
ID1, row 1
[2456-AA, 2457-AA, 2657-AA] into [2456-AA], [2457-AA], [2657-AA]

then perform the left join (similar to Vlookup in Excel)

df2 left join df1 by ID2 (can be done in several languages)